# Bug When I Click one person in Datagrid

Tags: c#

First My English it so bad, i hope you know what i want to ask you.

This is my code

```
private void dataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string MaNV = dataGrid.SelectedValue.ToString();
    Nhan_Vien nv = dsnhanvien.Single(a => a.MaNV.Trim() == MaNV);
    txtMaNV.Text = nv.MaNV;
    txtHo.Text = nv.Ho;
    txtTen.Text = nv.Ten_Dem;
    txtDiaChi.Text = nv.Dia_Chi;
    txtGioiTinh.Text = nv.Gioi_Tinh;
    txtLuong.Text = nv.Luong.ToString();
}
```

I get an error when i click 1 colum in my DataGrid

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Core.dll
>
> Additional information:
>
> Value cannot be null

Comment: On which line is the error? Please learn how to debug your code.

Comment: Set a break-point and run it in debug mode. What is the `MaNV` value?

Comment: this line Nhan_Vien nv = dsnhanvien.Single(a => a.MaNV.Trim() == MaNV);

Comment: MaNV it is String

Comment: Of course is a string, but it get `dataGrid.SelectedValue.ToString()` that I suppose is `null`.

Comment: Just replace dataGrid.SelectedValue.ToString(); line with  e.SelectedValue.ToString();

Comment: //dataGrid.SelectedValue.ToString(); line with e.SelectedValue.ToString();// It is not Working :(
How i can fix this mcNets :( Help me :(

Comment: Sorry for the mistaken close.

Comment: @David I just had the comment notification?

Comment: @stuartd Cool, wasn't sure if hammerers get pinged or not.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace of exception?

Comment: If MaNV is null in `a.MaNV.Trim()` , Trim will be called on null and can cause the exception. You could try using `a.MaNV?.Trim()` instead

Comment: Use the debugger to solve problems like this. It will tell you the line that was responsible for throwing the exception, and you can inspect the objects used in that line to see which one is null.

Comment: @Cody I Know a line but i dont know why MaNV get Null when i chose 1 information in my dataGrid

Comment: If any `Nhan_Vien` inside `dsnhanvien` has a `MaNV` that is null, the `Single` can throw the exception (on `Trim`). Did you try using `a.MaNV?.Trim()` ? (The extra `?` is to create a null-conditional operator)

Comment: Right ? dsnhanvien.Single(a => a.MaNV?.Trim() == MaNV); but i get erordoes not contain a definition for 'Single' and the best extension method OverLoad

Comment: With the line unchanged from the original (except the `?`) ?  `Nhan_Vien nv = dsnhanvien.Single(a => a.MaNV?.Trim() == MaNV);` If the code worked before, `Single` should still be valid. As long as `dsnhanvien` is a valid enumerable source and you have a `using System.Linq`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)